# Using Commands in my IRC Client

Tags: c#, client, irc

im currently trying to make a simple IRC Gui Client. Im using the SmartIrc4net as a base, as it seems to be the most supportive out of all of them, found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8323/SmartIrc4net-the-C-IRC-library

Now What I am having problem with is the action commands. For example to make yourself an oper, you would type

/oper admin password  or to changehost, would be /sethost mynewhost

My problem is that when I pass that value through a TextBox, instead of making me admin, or changing my host. My input just gets displayed as text in the chat.

Here is my code:

```
        string[] serverlist;
        serverlist = new string[] { "mydomain.com" };
        int port = 6667;
        string channel = "#MyChannel#";
        try
        {
            irc.Connect(serverlist, port);
            irc.Login("SmartIRC", "SmartIrc4net Test Bot");
            irc.RfcJoin(channel);

                irc.SendMessage(SendType.Message, channel, "/oper admin mypass");
                irc.SendMessage(SendType.Action, channel, "/sethost mynewhost");

            irc.Listen();
```

But when I pass those values, all it does is just display what I typed in the chat, without actually making me oper, or changing my sethost.

Is there anyway that I could actually make it pass commands through to the IRC server, instead of just displaying the raw text on the chat?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Study the IRC protocol. IRC client doesn't send the /oper to server as PRIVMSG, but as OPER command. You can start with running wireshark, using IRC client connected to some server, typing the command, and looking into WS what exactly is sent over wire.

Comment: Yeah I have just checked Wireshark and noticed that a normal message is sent using PRIVMSG, and commands such as OPER and SETHOST do not have the PRIVMSG Infront of it. Now how do I get my command to not have the PPRIVMSG Infront of it? Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are explicitly sending a message. IRC itself has no notion of `/commands`, this is done all in the client. What you are doing is to just send a message with a specific text that happens to start with `/`. I.e. what the server receives is

```
PRIVMSG #channel :/oper admin mypass
```

instead of

```
OPER admin mypass
```

You just need to figure out a way of sending raw IRC commands to the server. The page you linked to doesn't offer much documentation on that part, though. But judging from the layers this should be in either Layer 2 or Layer 1.

Comment: So is there any specific type of code that I would need to enter use so that it could convert my text into raw data?

Comment: If you get the command from a textbox, then you'd need to parse it to determine whether you want to just send a message or a command. `tbInput.Text.StartsWith("/")` might be a good condition to check in that case. Then you just need to figure out  what exactly you need to send and with what parameters.

Comment: Hi, Yeah Ive tried that but to no luck. But yeah I now see exactly what you mean, as I ran Wireshark and saw the PRIVMSG on the command when I sent a message. The raw data that is going to be inserted is not from a textbox, but will be specified in codebehind. Could you give me any tips on what I would need to do to send a msg without the PRIVMSG, So I could try and figure this out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of more options then SendMessages.

You have example irc.RfcOper(username, pasword) for Oper.

If you want to send raw data command for things it does not support on the fly example sethost you can just send a WriteLine directly.

irc.WriteLine("sethost mynewhost")

Open the IrcCommands.cs to see a list of commands and Rfc2812.cs to see how they are transfered.

I however recommend you to read or at least peek at Rfc2812 standard that you can find here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812

Comment: Hi, I have just checked the Rfc2812.cs and the IrcCommands.cs, Ive seen how it works, but it doesnt really show me how to ddo it. Do you think I should just add a sethost function in the class, and re compile it?

Comment: I already exactly wrote what you need to do. Check the two Code Lines.

Comment: OK I think I get your problem, your using a way to much to old version of SmartIrc4Net it's homepage is here http://www.meebey.net/projects/smartirc4net/ If you grabbed it from code project the version is 0.2.0 the latest is 0.4.5.1

Comment: Got it working by downloading the new Class library and I looked at how the oper command worked, and i just added a reference to the sethost. Got it working now, Thanks